# Failed to initialize transformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am running this workflow  which is supposed to load a file, but i am having the following error messages.

1. Internal error. Failed to initialize transformation [LKP_FILE_LOAD_ID{{BLD}}]. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support". There is a field 'TOT_CLM' which is a string that i've used LTRIM/RTRIM, but I used 'TO_INTEGER(v_TOT_CLM)' because the field is defined as integer in the target table.
2. The second  error message reads ‘can’t create file in the directory /utils/infa_cache/USS/vnd_HPS/.
3. The last error message is that ‘check file system permission and free space for possible failure’.

Answer (score 0):

Answers -

1. When you define a DB lookup in informatica and use SQL override, please use alias to columns. Alias name should be same as lookup port name.
   So, if a lookup port is 'TOT_CLM', then select clause should be -
   `SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((TOT_CLM)) as  TOT_CLM,... FROM claim_table ORDER BY KEY --`
   If you dont put alias, you get this kind of error. If you still have error pls let me know.
2. It looks obvious you haven't set cache directory. You can define it in session properties as well as globally. Pls refer to below pic, you can set it for your session.
3. This seems related to number 2 and should go away if you set correct directory. Please note if your table size is huge, you may run out of spaces. Please connect to informatica admin for this.

[image]

HTH

Comment: Hello, I have checked the lookup, inside the lookup and there is no select statement there. The button which says 'Generate SQL' is grey, so i can't click on it. I have also verified and the 'Lookup caching enabled' is checked. The table is not huge, there are 2 target tables, one with 14 ports and another with 5 ports. Regarding the TOT_CLM port, i'm using an IFF statement in my expression. This is how I have written it.              v_TOT_CLM = IIF( LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(FIELD22,1,6))) = '', NULL,  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(FIELD22,1,6))) ) and in the next line I have TOT_CLM = TO_INTEGER(v_TOT_CLM).

Comment: I have tried to get a screenshot but i'm unable to attach it here.

Comment: can you pls attach session logs? seems like something is missing.

Comment: I do not have the option to attach anything or even screenshot on this website. Any suggestion, how did you attached the screenshot to the first answer you suggested to me

Comment: post it as an answer. you should get enough space to load error part.

Comment: Another error message was that ‘Can’t create file in the directory /utils/infa_cache/USS/vnd_HPS/’, i've contacted our DBA to grant me the permission, this seem to have resolved the error message I first posted. Now the new error message is about a missing file or directory, '/infa_shared/USS/SrcFiles/vnd_HPS//OR_TOC', I think the file is supposed to be '/infa_shared/USS/SrcFiles/vnd_HPS/OR_TOC' with only one forward slash between S and O

Comment: Glad it partially resolved. Now, path or absolute path depends on location of the file. Can you check your unix/linux using putty what is the exact path of your file, make sure file/folder is writable/accessible by yourself and informatica. Thats all you need.

Comment: put the file name like OR_TOC. i think you are putting extra / for the file name.